# How to toggle a snackbar with a message coming from a ViewModel using an observer created from a fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, view, observers

`viewModel` is provided by the `MainActivity` that calls a fragment delegated to create this observer of a `msg` inside `onViewCreated`

```
viewModel.msg.observe(requireActivity(), Observer {
            if(it.isNotEmpty() && !it.isNullOrBlank()) {
                Snackbar.make(requireView().rootView, it, Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT)
                viewModel.onShowMsgComplete()
            }
        })
```

The `msg` is correctly received inside the observer, but the snackbar is not showing.

Answer (score 1):

It is a simple mistake, you have made. You are not showing the `Snackbar` by calling `.show()` method.

```
viewModel.msg.observe(requireActivity(), Observer {
        if(it.isNotBlank()) {
            Snackbar.make(requireView().rootView, it, Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            viewModel.onShowMsgComplete()
        }
    })
```

Comment: what are the downsides of creating the observer inside the fragment? isn't this leading to memory leaks?

Answer (score 0):

You created the SnackBar but didn't call show method and calling show() method on your SnackBar obj will solve your problem. But I think you should use

`viewModel.msg.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer {....`

instead of requiredActivity() when observing the liveData from fragment to respect the fragment view lifecycle and to prevent observing multiple times. You can found the detail [here](https://medium.com/@cs.ibrahimyilmaz/viewlifecycleowner-vs-this-a8259800367b).

You may also use [SingleLiveEvent](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/livedata-with-snackbar-navigation-and-other-events-the-singleliveevent-case-ac2622673150) instead of normal liveData to show notification like SnackBar since normal liveData holds its value and you may need to clear the value manually. But it is totally depended on your implementation.